# Prolog program little issue

Tags: swi-prolog

I have an issue:

When I press <kbd>5</kbd> to check if I have borrowed books after I borrowed one, the result is the borrowed books but also this part of code shows:

```
 eseguiScelta(Utente, _) :-
    write('Scelta non valida. Riprova.'), nl,
    menu(Utente).
```

(it has the job to display error message if I put something like a letter when the program asks for numbers or something else and goes back to menu)

```
:- dynamic libro/3.
:- dynamic prestito/3.

trim_whitespace(Input, Output) :-
    atom_string(InputAtom, Input),
    string_codes(InputAtom, InputCodes),
    phrase(trimmed_string(OutputCodes), InputCodes),
    string_codes(OutputAtom, OutputCodes),
    atom_string(Output, OutputAtom).

trimmed_string([]) --> [].
trimmed_string([H|T]) --> whitespace, [H], trimmed_string(T).

whitespace --> [C], { code_type(C, space) }, !, whitespace.
whitespace --> [].

% Definizioni dei fatti
libro('Il Signore degli Anelli', 'J.R.R. Tolkien', 5).
libro('1984', 'George Orwell', 3).
libro('La strada', 'Cormac McCarthy', 2).

% Predicati per la ricerca dei libri per titolo o autore
cercaLibriPerTitolo(Titolo, Libri) :-
    findall((Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili), libro(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili), Libri),
    Libri \= [].

cercaLibriPerAutore(Autore, Libri) :-
    trim_whitespace(Autore, AutoreTrimmed),
    downcase_atom(AutoreTrimmed, AutoreMinuscolo),
    debug(cerca_libri, 'Autore inserito: ~w', [AutoreMinuscolo]),
    findall((Titolo, AutoreDB, CopieDisponibili), (
        libro(Titolo, AutoreDB, CopieDisponibili),
        trim_whitespace(AutoreDB, AutoreDBTrimmed),
        downcase_atom(AutoreDBTrimmed, AutoreDBMinuscolo),
        sub_string(AutoreDBMinuscolo, _, _, _, AutoreMinuscolo)
    ), Libri),
    debug(cerca_libri, 'Libri trovati: ~w', [Libri]).

% Predicati per prendere in prestito un libro o restituire un libro
prendiInPrestito(Utente, Titolo, Autore) :-
    libro(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili),
    CopieDisponibili > 0,
    retract(libro(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili)),
    NuoveCopieDisponibili is CopieDisponibili - 1,
    assertz(libro(Titolo, Autore, NuoveCopieDisponibili)),
    (prestito(Utente, Titolo, VecchieCopiePrese) ->
        NuoveCopiePrese is VecchieCopiePrese + 1,
        retract(prestito(Utente, Titolo, VecchieCopiePrese)),
        assertz(prestito(Utente, Titolo, NuoveCopiePrese))
    ; assertz(prestito(Utente, Titolo, 1))).

restituisciLibro(Utente, Titolo, Autore) :-
    retract(prestito(Utente, Titolo, CopiePrese)),
    (
        CopiePrese > 1 ->
        NuoveCopiePrese is CopiePrese - 1,
        assertz(prestito(Utente, Titolo, NuoveCopiePrese))
    ;
        true
    ),
    libro(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili),
    NuoveCopieDisponibili is CopieDisponibili + 1,
    retract(libro(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili)),
    assertz(libro(Titolo, Autore, NuoveCopieDisponibili)).

% Predicato per controllare i prestiti di un utente
controllaPrestiti(Utente, Prestiti) :-
    findall((Titolo, Autore, CopiePrese), (
        prestito(Utente, Titolo, CopiePrese),
        libro(Titolo, Autore, _)
    ), Prestiti),
    Prestiti \= [],
    length(Prestiti, _).

% Predicato per l'interazione con l'utente
interazioneUtente :-
    write('Ciao! Inserisci il tuo nome utente: '),
    flush_output,
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Utente),
    menu(Utente).

menu(Utente) :-
    nl, write('Benvenuto, '), write(Utente), write('. Cosa desideri fare?'), nl,
    write('1. Cerca libri per titolo'), nl,
    write('2. Cerca libri per autore'), nl,
    write('3. Prendi in prestito un libro'), nl,
    write('4. Restituisci un libro'), nl,
    write('5. Controlla i prestiti'), nl,
    write('0. Esci'), nl,
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, SceltaCodes),
    atom_codes(SceltaAtom, SceltaCodes),
    atom_number(SceltaAtom, Scelta),
    eseguiScelta(Utente, Scelta).

eseguiScelta(Utente, 1) :-
    write('Inserisci il titolo del libro: '),
    flush_output(current_output),
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Titolo),
    atom_string(TitoloAtom, Titolo),
    cercaLibriPerTitolo(TitoloAtom, Libri),
    stampaLibri(Libri),
    menu(Utente).

eseguiScelta(Utente, 2) :-
    write('Inserisci l\'autore del libro: '),
    flush_output(current_output),
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Autore),
    trim_whitespace(Autore, AutoreTrimmed),
    cercaLibriPerAutore(AutoreTrimmed, Libri),
    stampaLibri(Libri),
    menu(Utente).

eseguiScelta(Utente, 3) :-
    write('Inserisci il titolo del libro da prendere in prestito: '),
    flush_output(current_output),
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Titolo),
    atom_string(TitoloAtom, Titolo),
    write('Inserisci l\'autore del libro da prendere in prestito: '),
    flush_output(current_output),
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Autore),
    atom_string(AutoreAtom, Autore),
    prendiInPrestito(Utente, TitoloAtom, AutoreAtom),
    write('Libro preso in prestito con successo.'), nl,
    menu(Utente).

eseguiScelta(Utente, 4) :-
    write('Inserisci il titolo del libro da restituire: '),
    flush_output(current_output),
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Titolo),
    atom_string(TitoloAtom, Titolo),
    write('Inserisci l\'autore del libro da restituire: '),
    flush_output(current_output),
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Autore),
    atom_string(AutoreAtom, Autore),
    restituisciLibro(Utente, TitoloAtom, AutoreAtom),
    write('Libro restituito con successo.'), nl,
    menu(Utente).

eseguiScelta(Utente, 5) :-
    controllaPrestiti(Utente, Prestiti),
    (Prestiti \= [] ->
        stampaPrestiti(Prestiti)
    ;
        write('Non hai alcun libro in prestito.'), nl
    ),
    menu(Utente).

eseguiScelta(_, 0) :-
    write('Grazie per aver utilizzato il nostro servizio. Arrivederci!').

eseguiScelta(Utente, _) :-
    write('Scelta non valida. Riprova.'), nl,
    menu(Utente).

% Funzione stampaLibri
stampaLibri(Libri) :-
    (Libri == [] ->
        write('Nessun libro trovato con i criteri di ricerca.'), nl
    ;
        stampaLibriDettagli(Libri)
    ).

stampaLibriDettagli([]).
stampaLibriDettagli([(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili)|T]) :-
    write('Titolo: '), write(Titolo), nl,
    write('Autore: '), write(Autore), nl,
    write('Copie disponibili: '), write(CopieDisponibili), nl,
    stampaLibriDettagli(T).

stampaPrestiti(Prestiti) :-
    calcolaTotalePrestiti(Prestiti, 0, TotalePrestiti),
    write('Hai '), write(TotalePrestiti), write(' libro/i in prestito:'), nl,
    stampaPrestitiDettagli(Prestiti).

calcolaTotalePrestiti([], Totale, Totale).
calcolaTotalePrestiti([(_, _, CopiePrese)|T], Accumulatore, Totale) :-
    NuovoAccumulatore is Accumulatore + CopiePrese,
    calcolaTotalePrestiti(T, NuovoAccumulatore, Totale).

stampaPrestitiDettagli([(Titolo, Autore, CopiePrese)|T]) :-
    write('Titolo: '), write(Titolo), nl,
    write('Autore: '), write(Autore), nl,
    write('Copie prese in prestito: '), write(CopiePrese), nl,
    nl,
    stampaPrestitiDettagli(T).

:- initialization(interazioneUtente).
```

Comment: does any of the other options work as intended?

Comment: Yes, all the other options work as intended

Comment: not familiar with prolog, however I would suggest to print the choice when user goes into the error branch. Is "5" actually parsed?

Comment: Yep it's parsed, it shows me the output succesfully, and the sentence "Scelta non valida. Riprova." appears only when the input is something like "./ etc", or when he expects a number and recieves a letter

Comment: my bad, didn't understand at first. Then I'd say, there is no nl after the list of "presi in prestito" is printed. Could it be that the printed output is parsed as input again, and therefore goes into the error branch?
You should be able to debug this by printing what caused the error branch to be triggered.

Comment: eseguiScelta(Utente, 5) :-
    (controllaPrestiti(Utente, Prestiti) ->
        stampaPrestiti(Prestiti),nl
    ;
        write('Non hai alcun libro in prestito al momento.'), nl
    ),
    menu(Utente),
    !.

I added nl after "stampaPrestiti" call that prints the list of books borrowed.
But "Scelta non valida.Riprova" still appears